# When parental record is deleted, are childrecord deleted automatically by accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is an example on Rails 3.2 [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) for accepts_nested_attributes_for:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :author
  has_many :pages

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :author, :pages
end
```

Our question is that if a book record is deleted, are child records of author and pages deleted automatically along with the book record? Or we have to explicitly delete the child records in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to set the `dependent` key.

```
has_many :pages, dependent: :destroy
```

As the OP points out there is another option for `delete_all`. The difference is that `delete_all` won't fire the model's `before_destroy` callbacks, it will just wipe them from the database.

This is beneficial because it doesn't require the Rails to load DB objects into Ruby, which is slow, but it also deletes them regardless of your defined callbacks.

Comment: @@Brian Wheeler, there is another option :delete_all. Between destroy and delete_all, is there difference if we just want to delete associated child records? Many Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean :delete_all is beneficial because it does not require the Rails to load DB objects into ruby?